# Algorithm to move an element to the front of a list in O(m sqrt(n)) time

Tags: algorithm

Given a number **n**, the initial list is (**i.e. the initial list is sorted and contains elements from 0 to n-1**):

```
[0, 1, 2, ... n - 1]
```

The input is a sequence of **m** numbers. For each number in the input, move the number to the front of the list, and print out the index of that number.

For example:

n = 5:

Input:

```
3 3 4 2
```

Output:

```
3 0 4 4
```

Explanation:
Given n = 5, the initial list is

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

We first move 3 to the front. The index of 3 in the list is 3.

```
[3, 0, 1, 2, 4]
```

Then we move 3 again to the front. Because it is already in the front, the index is 0.

```
[3, 0, 1, 2, 4]
```

Then, we move 4 to the front. The index of 4 is 4.

```
[4, 3, 0, 1, 2]
```

Lastly, we move 2 to the front. The index of 2 is 4.

```
[2, 4, 3, 0, 1]
```

I implemented a O(mn) solution easily by linearly searching for the index of an element for every move-to-front. However, I can't think of a way to do this within the required time complexity O(m sqrt(n)).

I think maybe since we do not need to return the actual list after the move-to-front's, we can somehow leverage this to reduce the amount of work. Maybe some additional data structures might help?

Comment: I don't follow the algorithm.  Can you make it any clearer?

Comment: If the array is not sorted, then I think the fastest you can find a number is `O(N)` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Well you never told us that the list was initially sorted...a very critial detail.  Update your question and _clearly_ lay out the problem, with all the intial caveats.

Comment: To be fair: this was stated in question version 1.0. But i have doubts about the problem-description somehow. The complexity has no m in it. Is that right? It can't be, right?

Comment: I don't understand the last comment. It would be probably best to link to the formal description of the task. Yes, we can try to keep some bookmarks like: pos 3 moved to front: all between 0,3 are shifted by 1; the positions of the remaining ones keep the same. But this looks like there is a worst-case input defeating this. So we are talking about worst-case analysis right (or amortized)? Details please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*O*(*m*√*n*) seems a bit strange to me, but you can get *O*(*m* log *n*) — which is asymptotically even better — by adapting a balanced binary search tree structure (such as a red–black tree) instead of using a literal list.

Specifically, you need a normal binary tree structure, *plus*:

- the nodes have a "subtree-size" property.

  - this will let you calculate the relative position (= list index) of a node in *O*(log *n*) time if you're starting from the root and navigating to it.
- instead of keeping nodes in order by their actual values (0 through *n*−1), each node will have an "identifier". Each time we move a node to the beginning of the list, we set its identifier to be a smaller number than we've used previously for any node (so 0, then −1, then −2, etc.). So we keep the nodes in order by this "identifier".

  - this will let you navigate to a node from the root of the tree given only its identifier.
  - this, plus the preceding, will let you calculate the relative position of a node, given its "identifier", in *O*(log *n*) time.
- a mapping from values to current node "identifiers". (Since your values conveniently range from 0 to n−1, this can just be an array of integers.)

  - this, plus the preceding, will let you calculate the relative position of a node, given only its value, in *O*(log *n*) time.
  - in fact, we don't even need to include the values inside the binary tree structure; the nodes *only* need the identifiers.
- logic to rebalance parent nodes, by "rotating" them as with a red–black tree, when they get too skewed. This can be done in *O*(log *n*) time, and it's essential, since you're going to be continually removing nodes from various parts of the tree and moving them to the leftmost leaf, so the tree will rapidly become very unbalanced if that's not corrected.

You can initialize the tree in *O*(*n*) time, and add or remove a node in *O*(log *n*) time.

Unfortunately, this approach involves a lot of bookkeeping to keep all the sizes updated and to keep everything balanced. That won't affect the algorithmic complexity, but will make for a messy implementation. Maybe someone else can think of something simpler? (Or alternatively, maybe someone else can think of something less "custom", where more of the bookkeeping is handled by an off-the-shelf `java.util.TreeMap` or `std::map` or whatnot?)

Comment: Simply store the index offsets? See my answer I posted simultaneously :-)

Comment: @m69: Hmm. I don't fully understand the "offset" idea, but it seems isomorphic to the "subtree-size" idea. It doesn't seem to solve the rest of the bookkeeping difficulties.

Comment: Well it doesn't require changing the structure of the tree or rebalancing it, or keeping pointers to anything.

Comment: @m69: Oh! I think I understand now. So you actually always keep your tree in the same order, but just keep track of the relative positions of certain nodes relative to their "parents"? I can't quite convince myself that that works -- I'll have to draw it out. If it *does* work, then it's very nice (and it means that you don't even need a literal tree; it can all be managed as an array, with logic to compute parent and child indices on the fly).

Comment: I ran through an example, and it seems to work. Unfortunately I don't have time to create a code example now. The root node requires different rules from the other nodes though, maybe that could be fixed by adding a root with the value n and storing the whole tree to the left of it; that would make the middle value a regular node.

Comment: @m69: I think I've actually convinced myself that your approach *doesn't* work. Suppose that the list at some point contains 10 followed by 43 followed by 11, and then the next input is 43. Nothing in your algorithm would touch the offset between 10 and 11, would it? (Assuming here that 10 is a leaf node with parent = 11, and that 43 is in a completely different part of the tree.) So I don't see how your approach could work.

Comment: @qwt185: Re: "I didn't quite get how you'd calculate the current list index of a node using the subtree-size property": The index of a node is the count of elements to its left. One way to calculate that is as the sum of the sizes of all left-subtrees of nodes that you descended into the right-subtrees of, plus the number of nodes that you descended into the right-subtrees of, plus the size of the left-subtree of the node itself.

Comment: @qwt185: Re: "Also, every time you rotate the tree or move an item to the front, wouldn't subtree-size need to be re-counted and it would take O(n)?": Rotating only affects the subtree-size of the two nodes being rotated. Adding or removing a node only affects its own subtree-size and those of its ancestors, which comes out to O(log n), not O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Imagine an indexed doubly-linked list. The index is an array `INDICES` of pointers, pointing at nodes numbered 0, √n, 2√n, ..., (n-1)√n. Each node also stores its own index number `IDX` (first √n nodes always store 0, next √n nodes store 1, ...; the indices get updated with each operation so that to keep this invariant).

There is also an array `NODES` of pointers pointing to the nodes. The array never changes.

Now finding an index of an arbitrary node and moving it to the front of the list is an O(√n) operation.

To identify and move node number 5:

1. `NODES[5]` is a pointer to the node that has the number 5.
2. Determine its current position in the list: count from `INDICES[NODES[5]->IDX]` until you find the number 5. This is O(√n).
3. Remove the node from the list and insert it to the front. This is O(1).
4. Update the `INDICES` array and the `IDX` fields of affected nodes. There are O(√n) items in `INDICES` to modify (make them to point to the previous element, `INDICES[i] = INDICES[i]->PREV`), and also O(√n) nodes that need their `IDX` field updated (`INDICES[i]->IDX = INDICES[i]->IDX + 1`).

Comment: @qwt185 oh yes sorry, a typo. Fixing.

Comment: Nice! Note that if the language has a built-in doubly-linked-list implementation (e.g. `java.util.LinkedList` or `std::list`), then you can modify this to use that, by making two changes: (1) instead of indexing into a single list, you can have an array of √*n* separate lists; and (2) instead of storing an array of nodes and keeping the "index number" in the node, you can just store an array of "index numbers" (now "list numbers", I guess). (Those changes are needed because doubly-linked-list implementations usually encapsulate their nodes, preventing outside access.)